# Installing Rancher by run docker image on RHEL 8.5 fails

Tags: rhel, rancher

I’m have a new VM based on RHEL 8.5 and tried to install Rancher using the below simple command from formal rancher page here (Getting Started with Kubernetes | Rancher Quick Start)

sudo docker run --privileged -d --restart=unless-stopped -p 80:80 -p 443:443 rancher/rancher

but after the container start it keep restarting & the below errors appears.

Any Idea?

```
    [root@redhat-vm-01 ~]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NA MES
e8fbd2a4d67e rancher/rancher “entrypoint.sh” 5 minutes ago Up 12 seconds 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, :::443->443/tcp tr usting_shockley
[root@redhat-vm-01 ~]# docker logs -f e8fbd2a4d67e
2022/01/05 20:42:24 [INFO] Rancher version v2.6.3 (3c1d5fac3) is starting
2022/01/05 20:42:24 [INFO] Rancher arguments {ACMEDomains: AddLocal:true Embed ded:false BindHost: HTTPListenPort:80 HTTPSListenPort:443 K8sMode:auto Debug:fal se Trace:false NoCACerts:false AuditLogPath:/var/log/auditlog/rancher-api-audit. log AuditLogMaxage:10 AuditLogMaxsize:100 AuditLogMaxbackup:10 AuditLevel:0 Feat ures: ClusterRegistry:}
2022/01/05 20:42:24 [INFO] Listening on /tmp/log.sock
2022/01/05 20:42:24 [INFO] Waiting for k3s to start
time=“2022-01-05T20:42:24Z” level=info msg=“Acquiring lock file /var/lib/rancher /k3s/data/.lock”
time=“2022-01-05T20:42:24Z” level=info msg=“Preparing data dir /var/lib/rancher/ k3s/data/e61cd97f31a54dbcd9893f8325b7133cfdfd0229ff3bfae5a4f845780a93e84c”
2022/01/05 20:42:25 [INFO] Waiting for k3s to start
2022/01/05 20:42:26 [INFO] Waiting for k3s to start
2022/01/05 20:42:28 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:42:30 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:42:32 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:42:34 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:42:36 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:42:48 [INFO] Running in single server mode, will not peer connecti ons
2022/01/05 20:42:48 [INFO] Applying CRD features.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:42:50 [INFO] Applying CRD navlinks.ui.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:42:50 [INFO] Applying CRD clusters.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:42:50 [INFO] Applying CRD apiservices.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:42:50 [INFO] Applying CRD clusterregistrationtokens.management.cat tle.io
2022/01/05 20:42:50 [INFO] Applying CRD settings.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:42:50 [INFO] Applying CRD preferences.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:42:50 [INFO] Applying CRD features.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:42:50 [INFO] Applying CRD clusterrepos.catalog.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:42:50 [INFO] Applying CRD operations.catalog.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:42:50 [INFO] Applying CRD apps.catalog.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:42:50 [INFO] Applying CRD fleetworkspaces.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:42:50 [INFO] Applying CRD bundles.fleet.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:42:50 [INFO] Applying CRD clusters.fleet.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:42:50 [INFO] Applying CRD managedcharts.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:42:50 [INFO] Applying CRD clusters.provisioning.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:42:50 [INFO] Applying CRD clusters.provisioning.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:42:51 [INFO] Applying CRD rkeclusters.rke.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:42:51 [INFO] Applying CRD rkecontrolplanes.rke.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:42:51 [INFO] Applying CRD rkebootstraps.rke.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:42:51 [INFO] Applying CRD rkebootstraptemplates.rke.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:42:51 [INFO] Applying CRD rkecontrolplanes.rke.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:42:51 [INFO] Applying CRD custommachines.rke.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:42:51 [INFO] Applying CRD clusters.cluster.x-k8s.io
2022/01/05 20:42:51 [INFO] Applying CRD machinedeployments.cluster.x-k8s.io
2022/01/05 20:42:51 [INFO] Applying CRD machinehealthchecks.cluster.x-k8s.io
2022/01/05 20:42:51 [INFO] Applying CRD machines.cluster.x-k8s.io
2022/01/05 20:42:51 [INFO] Applying CRD machinesets.cluster.x-k8s.io
2022/01/05 20:42:51 [INFO] Waiting for CRD machinesets.cluster.x-k8s.io to becom e available
2022/01/05 20:42:52 [INFO] Done waiting for CRD machinesets.cluster.x-k8s.io to become available
2022/01/05 20:42:52 [INFO] Creating CRD authconfigs.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:42:52 [INFO] Creating CRD groupmembers.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:43:23 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:43:25 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:43:27 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:43:29 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:43:35 [FATAL] k3s exited with: exit status 255
2022/01/05 20:43:53 [INFO] Rancher version v2.6.3 (3c1d5fac3) is starting
2022/01/05 20:43:53 [INFO] Rancher arguments {ACMEDomains: AddLocal:true Embed ded:false BindHost: HTTPListenPort:80 HTTPSListenPort:443 K8sMode:auto Debug:fal se Trace:false NoCACerts:false AuditLogPath:/var/log/auditlog/rancher-api-audit. log AuditLogMaxage:10 AuditLogMaxsize:100 AuditLogMaxbackup:10 AuditLevel:0 Feat ures: ClusterRegistry:}
2022/01/05 20:43:53 [INFO] Listening on /tmp/log.sock
2022/01/05 20:43:53 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:43:55 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:43:57 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:43:59 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:44:01 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:44:03 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:44:05 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:44:07 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:44:09 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:44:15 [FATAL] k3s exited with: exit status 255
2022/01/05 20:44:31 [INFO] Rancher version v2.6.3 (3c1d5fac3) is starting
2022/01/05 20:44:31 [INFO] Rancher arguments {ACMEDomains: AddLocal:true Embed ded:false BindHost: HTTPListenPort:80 HTTPSListenPort:443 K8sMode:auto Debug:fal se Trace:false NoCACerts:false AuditLogPath:/var/log/auditlog/rancher-api-audit. log AuditLogMaxage:10 AuditLogMaxsize:100 AuditLogMaxbackup:10 AuditLevel:0 Feat ures: ClusterRegistry:}
2022/01/05 20:44:31 [INFO] Listening on /tmp/log.sock
2022/01/05 20:44:31 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:44:33 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:44:35 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:44:37 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:44:39 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:44:41 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:44:43 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:44:45 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:44:50 [FATAL] k3s exited with: exit status 255
2022/01/05 20:45:08 [INFO] Rancher version v2.6.3 (3c1d5fac3) is starting
2022/01/05 20:45:08 [INFO] Rancher arguments {ACMEDomains: AddLocal:true Embed ded:false BindHost: HTTPListenPort:80 HTTPSListenPort:443 K8sMode:auto Debug:fal se Trace:false NoCACerts:false AuditLogPath:/var/log/auditlog/rancher-api-audit. log AuditLogMaxage:10 AuditLogMaxsize:100 AuditLogMaxbackup:10 AuditLevel:0 Feat ures: ClusterRegistry:}
2022/01/05 20:45:08 [INFO] Listening on /tmp/log.sock
2022/01/05 20:45:08 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:45:10 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:45:12 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:45:14 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:45:16 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:45:18 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:45:20 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:45:22 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:45:24 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:45:26 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:45:28 [INFO] Running in single server mode, will not peer connecti ons
2022/01/05 20:45:28 [INFO] Applying CRD features.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:45:29 [INFO] Applying CRD navlinks.ui.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:45:29 [INFO] Applying CRD clusters.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:45:29 [INFO] Applying CRD apiservices.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:45:29 [INFO] Applying CRD clusterregistrationtokens.management.cat tle.io
2022/01/05 20:45:29 [INFO] Applying CRD settings.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:45:29 [INFO] Applying CRD preferences.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:45:30 [INFO] Applying CRD features.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:45:30 [INFO] Applying CRD clusterrepos.catalog.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:45:30 [INFO] Applying CRD operations.catalog.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:45:30 [INFO] Applying CRD apps.catalog.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:45:30 [INFO] Applying CRD fleetworkspaces.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:45:30 [INFO] Applying CRD managedcharts.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:45:31 [FATAL] failed to update managedcharts.management.cattle.io apiextensions.k8s.io/v1, Kind=CustomResourceDefinition for managedcharts.manage ment.cattle.io: Patch “https://127.0.0.1:6443/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1/custo mresourcedefinitions/managedcharts.management.cattle.io?timeout=15m0s”: EOF
2022/01/05 20:45:47 [INFO] Rancher version v2.6.3 (3c1d5fac3) is starting
2022/01/05 20:45:47 [INFO] Rancher arguments {ACMEDomains: AddLocal:true Embed ded:false BindHost: HTTPListenPort:80 HTTPSListenPort:443 K8sMode:auto Debug:fal se Trace:false NoCACerts:false AuditLogPath:/var/log/auditlog/rancher-api-audit. log AuditLogMaxage:10 AuditLogMaxsize:100 AuditLogMaxbackup:10 AuditLevel:0 Feat ures: ClusterRegistry:}
2022/01/05 20:45:47 [INFO] Listening on /tmp/log.sock
2022/01/05 20:45:47 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:45:49 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:45:51 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:45:53 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:45:55 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:45:57 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:45:59 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:46:01 [INFO] Running in single server mode, will not peer connecti ons
2022/01/05 20:46:01 [INFO] Applying CRD features.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:46:03 [INFO] Applying CRD navlinks.ui.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:46:03 [INFO] Applying CRD clusters.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:46:03 [FATAL] failed to update clusters.management.cattle.io apiex tensions.k8s.io/v1, Kind=CustomResourceDefinition for clusters.management.cattl e.io: Patch “https://127.0.0.1:6443/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1/customresourced efinitions/clusters.management.cattle.io?timeout=15m0s”: EOF
2022/01/05 20:46:22 [INFO] Rancher version v2.6.3 (3c1d5fac3) is starting
2022/01/05 20:46:22 [INFO] Rancher arguments {ACMEDomains: AddLocal:true Embed ded:false BindHost: HTTPListenPort:80 HTTPSListenPort:443 K8sMode:auto Debug:fal se Trace:false NoCACerts:false AuditLogPath:/var/log/auditlog/rancher-api-audit. log AuditLogMaxage:10 AuditLogMaxsize:100 AuditLogMaxbackup:10 AuditLevel:0 Feat ures: ClusterRegistry:}
2022/01/05 20:46:22 [INFO] Listening on /tmp/log.sock
2022/01/05 20:46:22 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:46:24 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:46:26 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:46:28 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:46:30 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:46:32 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:46:34 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:46:36 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:46:38 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:46:40 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:46:46 [FATAL] k3s exited with: exit status 255
2022/01/05 20:47:03 [INFO] Rancher version v2.6.3 (3c1d5fac3) is starting
2022/01/05 20:47:03 [INFO] Rancher arguments {ACMEDomains: AddLocal:true Embed ded:false BindHost: HTTPListenPort:80 HTTPSListenPort:443 K8sMode:auto Debug:fal se Trace:false NoCACerts:false AuditLogPath:/var/log/auditlog/rancher-api-audit. log AuditLogMaxage:10 AuditLogMaxsize:100 AuditLogMaxbackup:10 AuditLevel:0 Feat ures: ClusterRegistry:}
2022/01/05 20:47:03 [INFO] Listening on /tmp/log.sock
2022/01/05 20:47:03 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:47:05 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:47:07 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:47:09 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:47:11 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:47:13 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:47:15 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:47:17 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:47:19 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:47:21 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:47:23 [INFO] Running in single server mode, will not peer connecti ons
2022/01/05 20:47:23 [INFO] Applying CRD features.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:47:24 [INFO] Applying CRD navlinks.ui.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:47:24 [INFO] Applying CRD clusters.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:47:24 [INFO] Applying CRD apiservices.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:47:24 [INFO] Applying CRD clusterregistrationtokens.management.cat tle.io
2022/01/05 20:47:24 [INFO] Applying CRD settings.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:47:24 [INFO] Applying CRD preferences.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:47:24 [INFO] Applying CRD features.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:47:25 [INFO] Applying CRD clusterrepos.catalog.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:47:25 [INFO] Applying CRD operations.catalog.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:47:25 [INFO] Applying CRD apps.catalog.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:47:25 [INFO] Applying CRD fleetworkspaces.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:47:25 [INFO] Applying CRD managedcharts.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:47:25 [INFO] Applying CRD clusters.provisioning.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:47:25 [INFO] Applying CRD clusters.provisioning.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:47:25 [INFO] Applying CRD rkeclusters.rke.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:47:25 [INFO] Applying CRD rkecontrolplanes.rke.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:47:25 [INFO] Applying CRD rkebootstraps.rke.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:47:25 [INFO] Applying CRD rkebootstraptemplates.rke.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:47:25 [INFO] Applying CRD rkecontrolplanes.rke.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:47:25 [INFO] Applying CRD custommachines.rke.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:47:25 [INFO] Applying CRD clusters.cluster.x-k8s.io
2022/01/05 20:47:26 [INFO] Applying CRD machinedeployments.cluster.x-k8s.io
2022/01/05 20:47:26 [INFO] Applying CRD machinehealthchecks.cluster.x-k8s.io
2022/01/05 20:47:26 [FATAL] failed to list apiextensions.k8s.io/v1, Kind=CustomR esourceDefinition for machinehealthchecks.cluster.x-k8s.io: Get “https://127.0. 0.1:6443/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1/customresourcedefinitions?labelSelector=ob jectset.rio.cattle.io%!F(MISSING)hash%!D(MISSING)7372e5228a5d4df32e62db137ea6bf4 69c35d4c4&timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connection refused
2022/01/05 20:47:44 [INFO] Rancher version v2.6.3 (3c1d5fac3) is starting
2022/01/05 20:47:44 [INFO] Rancher arguments {ACMEDomains: AddLocal:true Embed ded:false BindHost: HTTPListenPort:80 HTTPSListenPort:443 K8sMode:auto Debug:fal se Trace:false NoCACerts:false AuditLogPath:/var/log/auditlog/rancher-api-audit. log AuditLogMaxage:10 AuditLogMaxsize:100 AuditLogMaxbackup:10 AuditLevel:0 Feat ures: ClusterRegistry:}
2022/01/05 20:47:44 [INFO] Listening on /tmp/log.sock
2022/01/05 20:47:44 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:47:46 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:47:48 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:47:50 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:47:52 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:47:54 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:47:56 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on t he server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:48:02 [FATAL] k3s exited with: exit status 255
2022/01/05 20:48:20 [INFO] Rancher version v2.6.3 (3c1d5fac3) is starting
2022/01/05 20:48:20 [INFO] Rancher arguments {ACMEDomains: AddLocal:true Embed ded:false BindHost: HTTPListenPort:80 HTTPSListenPort:443 K8sMode:auto Debug:fal se Trace:false NoCACerts:false AuditLogPath:/var/log/auditlog/rancher-api-audit. log AuditLogMaxage:10 AuditLogMaxsize:100 AuditLogMaxbackup:10 AuditLevel:0 Feat ures: ClusterRegistry:}
2022/01/05 20:48:20 [INFO] Listening on /tmp/log.sock
2022/01/05 20:48:21 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:48:23 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:48:25 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get “https:// 127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connect ion refused
2022/01/05 20:48:27 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on the server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:48:29 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on the server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:48:31 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on the server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:48:33 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on the server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:48:35 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on the server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:48:37 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on the server (“apiserver not ready”) has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/01/05 20:48:39 [INFO] Running in single server mode, will not peer connections
2022/01/05 20:48:39 [INFO] Applying CRD features.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:48:39 [INFO] Applying CRD navlinks.ui.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:48:40 [INFO] Applying CRD clusters.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:48:40 [INFO] Applying CRD apiservices.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:48:40 [INFO] Applying CRD clusterregistrationtokens.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:48:40 [INFO] Applying CRD settings.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:48:40 [INFO] Applying CRD preferences.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:48:40 [INFO] Applying CRD features.management.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:48:40 [INFO] Applying CRD clusterrepos.catalog.cattle.io
2022/01/05 20:48:41 [FATAL] Get “https://127.0.0.1:6443/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1/customresourcedefinitions/clusterrepos.catalog.cattle.io?timeout=15m0s”: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connection refused
```

[Container restarted every 40 second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvAEO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently something is incompatible with the kernel from 8.5.
It has to do with systemd and something else.

I have tried a lot to get it to work, but the only thing that worked for me was to downgrade systemd+kernel to the versions from 8.4.

So to do that you need to add the 8.4 repo back - and do a

```
sudo dnf update
sudo dnf install kernel-4.18.0-305.25.1.el8_4.x86_64 systemd-239-45.el8_4.3.x86_64
```

That is the only thing I have gotten to work so far. Obviously I hope that the people working on rancher fixes it. It has something to do with cgroups - and apparently the rancher version is not compatible with the 8.5 version of systemd & kernel.
You can check out this [post](https://forums.rancher.com/t/help-on-issue-fatal-k3s-exited-with-exit-status-255/36373/6)